# Hide image evenly on both sides on variable width site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a HTML5 site in MVC5 that is of variable width and at its maximum width there's an image showing in full inside a div. As the site narrows, currently it takes away content from the right of the image, but I want it to take it away evenly from either side.

The outer wrapper div of the site is defined to keep the site centered, with styles as follows:

```
#wrapper {
    min-width: 1152px;
    max-width: 1680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

The div that contains the image has the following styles:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Currently I've just got the image within an `img` tag inside the main div, like follows:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Home/home.jpg")"/>
```

How can I make the image narrow evenly on both sides as the site narrows and conversely, show the image on both sides evenly as it widens again up to its maximum? Is there a way in CSS, or will I need to do something in Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Use percentages in CSS.

Comment: Percentages to hide bits of the image as the site narrows, rather than scale the image? Do you have an example please?

Comment: How should the image be aligned within the `#main` container? Should it be displayed at the center horizontally? or at a side?

Comment: I would use `@import 'url.css' (min-width:500px);` or `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='(min-width:500px)' href='url.css' />`, or something like that, so your CSS is predefined, if you're just testing for Browser size. If you want it when the Browser is resized, you must use the JavaScript `onresize` Event.

Comment: @HashemQolami centered horizontally.

Comment: When it's resized, or also to take into account any possible resolution between my min and max widths on the site. I could look at a jQuery solution - was just hoping there'd be a CSS solution I could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) is an option, you could position the image by `left: 50%` and then use a negative `translateX` to make it centered.

This way it will show/hide the image evenly on both sides:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/ceniw/1/edit)**

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x350" alt="">
</div>
```

```css
.img-container { overflow: hidden; }

img {
  vertical-align: middle; /* remove the vertical gap under inline level elements */

  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

It's worth noting that [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is supported in IE9 and newer.

Comment: A min-width needs to be set on the image so that it stops shrinking and starts overflowing.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Home/home.jpg")" style="background-position: center;"/>
```

It will center the background in the middle of the elemnt so that it should narrow it evenly

Comment: `src` is foreground not `background`, and this won't control size of image.

Comment: I could make the image background, but I'd prefer it to be content rather than a background-image property, plus on some other pages I'll have it cycling through different images and I'll doubt I'll be able to do that easily with jQuery and background images?